# Execute a command at a given interval (no cron) + redirect output to growl-like notification

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm looking to execute a command at a given interval and display the result in a growl-like window. Is there an easy way to do that?

For example, I've a job running that resizes images and I would like to execute `ls|wc -l` every 5 minutes to check the progress.

Comment: You say "growl-like", but then specify command-line. That makes the question ambiguous. Do you want GUI notifications from your command-line script, or are you okay with an all-in-the-terminal-window approach?

Comment: I want to execute a command in a terminal, continue to work in other windows and have notifications about the progress of the command running in the terminal. So, not ok for all-in-the-terminal-window approach ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) and have it execute your notification when there are changes in the directory. In your script that is run by `incron` could [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) a file, if it's been at least five minutes since it was last touched send your notification (using [`zenity`](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity), or similar).

**Edit:**

Another option is `notify-send` which is usually in a package named something like "libnotify".

This will display a file count near the upper-left corner for three seconds every five minutes (and stop after 30 minutes):

```
start=$SECONDS
while (( $SECONDS < start + 30 * 60 ))
do
    if (( ! ( ($SECONDS - start) % (5 * 60) ) ))
    then
        notify-send --expire-time=3000 --hint=int:x:0 --hint=int:y:0 $(ls | wc -l)&
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Of course, you could just do `sleep 5m`.

Comment: Thanks but zenity is not really what I want. I'm looking for something like a transparent window that appears on the top-left corner of the screen and automatically fades away after a few seconds.

Comment: @Pascal: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis, that's exactly what I was looking for :-) BTW, the package (on Ubuntu) is libnotify-bin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use watch like:

```
$ watch -n5 "ls | wc -l"
```

This will execute the command `ls | wc -l` every five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Like Khaled but with a twist:

```
watch -d -n 5 'ls | wc -l'
```

`-d` will show differences from one snapshot to the next, making it obvious when things change.